# Problem with adding two elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sum

I'm trying to write a function for blurring images. (I'm aware of ***imfilter*** command. Just trying to implement it in my own way). I've the following function which takes a uint8 matrix as argument ***img***.

```
function output=bl(img,w)
row=size(img,1);
col=size(img,2);
g_size=(2*w+1)^2;
output=uint8(zeros(row,col));
for ii=1:row
    for jj=1:col
        s=0;
        corner=[ii jj]-w;
        for r=corner(1):(corner(1)+(2*w))
            for c=corner(2):(corner(2)+(2*w))
                if((r>0 && r<=row) && (c>0 && c<=col))
                    s=s+img(r,c); %PROBLEMATIC LINE
                    fprintf('The value of s is %d\n',s);
                end
            end
        end     
        m=s/g_size;
        output(ii,jj)=fix(m);
        s=0;
    end
end
end
```

I'm having trouble with the line marked as "PROBLEMATIC LINE". The line of code was supposed to add previous value of s with img(c,r). But surprisingly each time the line runs, the previous value of s becomes 0. What am I doing wrong here? How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by “previous value becomes zero?

Comment: Actually the initial value of s was 0. And when s=s+img(r,c); runs for the first time the value becomes 255. The next time when the line runs the value of s remains 255. So I thought somehow s is being initialized to 0. But I was wrong, as I messed up with data types. Max has cleared up my confusion in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your *problematic line* casts the result to a `uint8`. If you add more and more integers, you will eventually exceed the limit value of 255 (more cannot be represented with 8 bit). See:

```
s = 0 % s = 0; class double
s = s + uint8(200) % s = 200; class uint8
s = s + uint8(200) % s = 255; class uint8
```

The reason for this is that MATLAB cannot add different types, so it implicitly cast its default type `double` to a `unit8`. You will see that this fails if you would initialize `s` as a certain type other than `double`

```
s = uint16(0);
s = s + uint8(200) % this will produce an error
```

> **Error using  +**
>   Integers can only be combined with integers of the
>   same class, or scalar doubles.

You will get around this by casting the image manually:

```
s = uint16(0) % s = 0; class uint16
img = uint8(200); % img = 200; class uint8
s = s + uint16( img ) % s = 200; class uint16
s = s + uint16( img ) % s = 400; class uint16
```

`uint16` should suite your needs as you can represent numbers up to `2^16-1` = 65535 with it.

Comment: This is the solution to the likely actual problem that OP is facing, but it doesn’t address OP’s claimed problem that “the previous value of s becomes 0.” I’m still hoping to find out what that means. :)

Comment: Also, there’s no reason to not do the accumulation in a `double`. Operations on integers are actually slower in MATLAB because it implements saturated arithmetic, which requires a test for each arithmetic operation performed.

Comment: When working with images, it is often beter to use a memory efficient caluclation than striving for speed. | The hypothesis is that the "previous value of s becomes 0" might be a mixup that not `s` becomes zero but `img` is not added to `s`

Comment: I agree, but in this case it’s a single value. It should be fine to store 8 bytes here. After all, the loop counters are also all 8 bytes each! :)

Comment: Yes. What @max said is what I actually wanted to mean. Sorry for not being clear enough